# XOR of values present in subset of array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, dynamic-programming

Given an array of A of size n containing only positive integers. Let l be the largest number in array A. Generate an array B of size 0 to l such that B[j] is the size of largest subset of array A whose XOR value is equal to j.

Constraints:
Size of the array A can be from 1 to 10000.
Elements in array A can range from 1 to 1000.

For example: If array A has (1,2,3,4) then array B would be generated as below.

B(0)=3 as the largest subset having XOR value 0 is (1,2,3)  and has size 3.

B(1)=2 as the largest subset having XOR value 1 is (2,3)  and has size 2.

B(2)=2 as the largest subset having XOR value 2 is (1,3)  and has size 2.

B(3)=2 as the largest subset having XOR value 3 is (1,2)  and has size 2.

B(4)=4 as the largest subset having XOR value 4 is (1,2,3,4)  and has size 4.

My brute-force approach: Generate all non empty subsets of array A and calculate XOR of each subset and save maximum size subset having XOR value j in B[j].

Is there a more efficient approach to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this would work, I have added comments for help

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define max(a, b) (a>b?a:b)
int dp[10005][1001]= {0};
int main() {
    // your code goes here
    int n, a[10005]={0}, m, i,j, ans[1005]={0};
    // n denotes number of elements in array, m denotes the range(0, m) where you want to loop
    scanf("%d%d",&n,&m);
    for(i=1; i<=n; i++){
        // taking input
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<=10000;i++){
        for(j=0;j<=1000;j++){
            dp[i][j] = -1;
        }
    }
    dp[0][0] = 0;
    // dp[i][j] denotes what's the max num of elements whose xor = j using the first i elements
    for(i=1; i<=n; i++){
        for(j=0; j<=1000; j++){
            if(dp[i-1][j] != -1){
                // if j was possible using i-1 elements the using a[i] (a[i]^j) can be made using i elements
                dp[i][j^a[i]] = max(dp[i][j^a[i]], dp[i-1][j]+1);
            }
            dp[i][j] = max(dp[i][j], dp[i-1][j]);
            if(dp[i][j] != -1){
                ans[j] = max(ans[j], dp[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<=m;i++){
        printf("%d\n", ans[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

check the output at http://ideone.com/QuICHN

Comment: i never thought this could be done using dynamic programming. Can you point me to the link which better explains this approach?

Comment: I don't have a link as such, I can try to update the answer to explain this in a better way